# How 'before' and 'after' variables gets updated after call of put() method of LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

`LinkedHashMap` extends `HashMap`. Method `put()` is not present in `LinkedHashMap.java` code. So I consider that if I can call `put()` method in program below, then it must be inherited `put()` method from `HashMap`.

```
import java.util.*;
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                LinkedHashMap<Key, String> h=new LinkedHashMap<>(7);
                h.put(new Key(3), "Hi");
                h.put(new Key(1), "Hello");
                h.put(new Key(9), "hru");
                System.out.println(h);
        }
}
```

Key.java is:

```
class Key
{
        int i = 0;
        Key(int i)
        {
                this.i=i;
        }
        public int hashCode()
        {
                return i;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
                return i+"";
        }
}
```

It must have to maintain 'after' and 'before' references to preserve insertion order: http://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/mediaembed/images/3751/7481/original.jpg

But `put()` method in `HashMap` is not aware of these variables. Then how call on `put()` maintaining these variables?

I also cannot find `createEntry()` method in `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap` code.

I am using:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are callback methods called (indirectly) by `HashMap` operations such as `put` and `remove` which `LinkedHashMap` overrides :

```
// Callbacks to allow LinkedHashMap post-actions
void afterNodeAccess(Node<K,V> p) { }
void afterNodeInsertion(boolean evict) { }
void afterNodeRemoval(Node<K,V> p) { }
```

This allows `LinkedHashMap` to maintain a doubly linked list of entries, which `HashMap` knows nothing about.

Besides those methods, `LinkedHashMap` overrides `newNode()` to return an instance of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`, which contains `before` and `after` references.

EDIT :

Seeing your `Keys` class, it appears you forgot to override `equals`, which means you can add duplicate keys to your `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @KevinEsche The Keys class was just added to the question, I'll edit my answer.